# Android SwipeGesture working only in one direction,i have no clue why?

Tags: android, audio-player, swipe-gesture, android-gesture, android-music-player

i am making a music player for android but i recently updated it with swipe gestures but the thing is that only one gesture(bottom swipe is working) i checked the swipe gesture class and nothing seems to be wrong in that

here is the code of my implementation

```
LinearLayout LL=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.LL);
LL.setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeTouchListener() {
            public void onSwipeTop() {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
            public void onSwipeRight() {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();

            }
            public void onSwipeLeft() {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();

            }
            public void onSwipeBottom() {
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
            }
        });
```

and here is my  class for swiping

```
public class OnSwipeTouchListener  extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

    private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

    public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent motionEvent) {
       // super.onTouch(view, motionEvent);
        return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent);
    }

    private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 70;
        private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 60;

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            boolean result = false;
            try {
                float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY))
                {
                    if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) 
                    {
                        if (diffX > 0)
                        {
                            onSwipeRight();
                        } 
                        else 
                        {
                            onSwipeLeft();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else 
                {
                    if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD)
                    {
                        if (diffY > 0) 
                        {
                            onSwipeBottom();
                        } else {
                            onSwipeTop();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception exception) {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }

    public void onSwipeRight() {
    }

    public void onSwipeLeft() {
    }

    public void onSwipeTop() {
    }

    public void onSwipeBottom() {
    }
}
```

Comment: But in my case swipe is working in one direction....can you debug the code??if not why are you posting such questions with totally different approach???first i have to understand his code,then his problem and then change it suiting to my needs and then check if its working for me or not...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like there was no problem with the code....but the problem was with the  view,the xml file..

the linear layout was not filling the whole space...so the only swipe which was working was the bottom swipe...and that too only in the top region.(where the linear layout existed)......